# Rails: Accessing a variable where the name of the variable was passed into the function as an argument

Tags: ruby

```
#string = "I love long strolls on the beach"
def keyword(string)
  @keyword_array = ["ball","sand","spade"]

  ball = ["red","green","blue"]
  sand = ["beach","playbox","sea"]
  spade = ["garden","beach","cards"]

  @keyword_array.each do |item|
  new_array = item
    puts item # on the first loop for example this returns 'ball'
  end
end
```

As you can see in the example above when I iterate through the first loop it returns the string ball (just using the first loop as an example, its the same on all loops) but I want to assign new_array with the value of `["red","green","blue"]` from the ball array as I will be passing this array to a function.

So basically instead of assigning the ball array, it assigns the name of the array as a string.

I tried a ton of things including using #{item}, instance_variable_set but nothing works. I have a feeling I do not know the correct terminology for this example so I can't find the right answer.

I had a similar situation where I was passing the method name as a variable and I did this to fix it:

```
return method("#{name}").call
```

but that was for a def/method. How would I do it for a variable?

Go easy on me, new to rails :)

Comment: Being a pure-Ruby question, this should have a 'ruby' tag and no rails tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to accomplish can be done using [eval](https://apidock.com/ruby/Binding/eval), but be careful about how you use it since this can execute any code within that expression, so be sure you only use it on flows where you have full control (avoid the use of this when user input is part of the `eval` call).

```rb
a = 'pepe'

pepe = 'pepito'

p a

p eval a
```

The first `put` will print 'pepe', the second one will print 'pepito' (the value of the `pepe` variable), you can test that snippet [here](https://repl.it/languages/ruby?v2=1).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do the contents of `@keyword_array` have to be a string?

We can avoid doing tricky things like `call` or `send` if we just store the references to the arrays in `@keyword_array`.

```
#string = "I love long strolls on the beach"
def keyword(string)
  ball = ["red","green","blue"]
  sand = ["beach","playbox","sea"]
  spade = ["garden","beach","cards"]

  @keyword_array = [ball, sand, spade]

  @keyword_array.each do |item|
    new_array = item
    puts item
  end
end
```